# What is the most elegant way to find index of duplicate items in C# List

Tags: c#, search, list, duplicates

I've got a `List<string>` that contains duplicates and I need to find the indexes of each.

What is the most elegant, efficient way other than looping through all the items.  I'm on .NET 4.0 so LINQ is an option.  I've done tons of searching and connect find anything.

Sample data:

```
var data = new List<string>{"fname", "lname", "home", "home", "company"}();
```

I need to get the indexes of "home".

Comment: How many items are in the list? Is it sorted? Is it sortable? How are you comparing for equality? Does it have to work for any data type or just strings? Why are you putting duplicates in the list in the first place? You asked for most elegant AND most efficient but those are frequently opposites; which is actually more important?

Comment: Why do you say "other than looping through the items"? Someone has to loop through the items at some point - whether it is you or linq that does it is surely irrelevant.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can create an object from each item containing it's index, then group on the value and filter out the groups containing more than one object. Now you have a grouping list with objects containing the text and their original index:

```
var duplicates = data
  .Select((t,i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
  .GroupBy(g => g.Text)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Comment: Thanks this was the most elegant solution I could find

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var data = new List<string> { "fname", "lname", "home", "home", "company" };
        foreach (var duplicate in FindDuplicates(data))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Duplicate: {0} at index {1}", duplicate.Item1, duplicate.Item2);
        }
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Tuple<T, int>> FindDuplicates<T>(IEnumerable<T> data)
    {
        var hashSet = new HashSet<T>();
        int index = 0;
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            if (hashSet.Contains(item))
            {
                yield return Tuple.Create(item, index);
            }
            else
            {
                hashSet.Add(item);
            }
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this

```
var data = new List<string>{"fname", "lname", "home", "home", "company"};

            var duplicates = data
                            .Select((x, index) => new { Text = x, index})
                            .Where( x => (  data
                                            .GroupBy(i => i)
                                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                                            .Select(g => g.Key).ToList()
                                          ).Contains(x.Text));
```

Comment: Interresting, but very inefficient. You should create the lookup once instead of once for each item in the list. To be efficient the lookup should be a HashSet, not a List.

Answer (score 0):

I myself needed to find and remove the duplicates from list of strings. I first searched the indexes of duplicate items and then filtered the list in functional way using LINQ, without mutating the original list:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> RemoveDuplicates(IEnumerable<string> items)
{
    var duplicateIndexes =  items.Select((item, index) => new { item, index })
                            .GroupBy(g => g.item)
                            .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                            .SelectMany(g => g.Skip(1), (g, item) => item.index);
    return items.Where((item, index) => !duplicateIndexes.Contains(index));
}
```