# Find indexes of duplicate strings in C# List

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a List of strings:

```
["String1"]
["String2"]
["String1"]
["String3"]
["String2"]
["String1"]
```

That I need to search and find the indexes of "String1" in the List and also count how many times "String1" occurred.  I've reviewed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718822/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-find-index-of-duplicate-items-in-c-sharp-list) but I'm new to this type of coding in C# and I'm unclear how to extract the index values, so if you could explain how to use the solution, that'd be great!

Comment: @Daniel. The OP actually mentions that question in his own question, so apparently needs more detail than it provided.

Comment: @mark - please as your questions to it over here.

Comment: @Mark Do you really only need the indicies for `"String1"`, or do you want the indicies for *all* strings? If you only care about `"String1"` then there's a much simpler solution using a basic loop.

Answer (score 14):

The code from the other answer, which I will duplicate here for reference,

```
var duplicates = data
  .Select((t,i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
  .GroupBy(g => g.Text)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Returns an `IEnumerable` of [`IGrouping`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx), which is itself an `IEnumerable` of an anonymous type. You can get the indexes out of the result like this:

```
foreach(var group in duplicates)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Duplicates of {0}:", group.Key)
    foreach(var x in group)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("- Index {0}:", x.Index)
    }
}
```

However, if all you want to do is get a list of indexes, you can use the [`SelectMany`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631.aspx) extension method:

```
var duplicateIndexes = data
  .Select((t,i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
  .GroupBy(g => g.Text)
  .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
  .SelectMany(g => g, (g, x) => x.Index);
```

This will return an `IEnumerable` of `int`'s.

Comment: Why the downvote? If there is something wrong in my answer, I'd be happy to correct it.

Comment: its plagiarism from the other question.

Comment: @DanielA.White OP's question was specifically about trying to get a better understanding about *that* code. I copied it here for better context (since OP didn't included it in the actual question). That seems fairly reasonable to me, since I did provide a explanation which addressed OP's specific question. Would you prefer that I simply link to the answer (which might be edited in the future, ruining this context), or perhaps edit the question to contain the code OP is confused about?

Answer (score 2):

Start with understanding the code from the answer (see my comments below):

```
// Produce an enumeration of Index/Text pairs
var duplicates = data
    // First, add the index to the value by using Select with an anonymous type
    .Select((t,i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
    // Next, group the results by the content of the string
    .GroupBy(g => g.Text)
    // Finally, keep only groups with more than one item.
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1);
```

Let's modify it to suit our purposes:

```
// Produce an enumeration of Indexes of "String1"
var allString1Indexes = data
    // First, add the index to the value by using Select with an anonymous type
    .Select((t,i) => new { Index = i, Text = t })
    // Keep only the "String1" items
    .Where(p => p.Text == "String1")
    // Use only indexes
    .Select(p => p.Index);
```

You can iterate the result now, and print all indexes of `"String1"`:

```
foreach (var i in allString1Indexes) {
    Console.WriteLine("String1 is found at index {0}", i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ToDictionary` method to get `Dictionary<string, List<int>>`:

```
var duplicated = data.Select((x, i) => new { i, x })
                     .GroupBy(x => x.x)
                     .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
                     .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Select(x => x.i).ToList());
```

Under every `Key` there is a list of indexes where the string actually occurs in source list.