# C# Display all Indices of String List Duplicates From User Input

Tags: c#, search, duplicates, indices

I am really new and I read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18547993/find-indexes-of-duplicate-strings-in-c-sharp-list) but when I literally tested the code answers somehow the .Select .GroupBy is red regardless of what I add on the using choices above.

My goal is to display all indices of duplicates from a string list with user input as text. For example,

```
        List<string> intList = new List<string>();
        intList.Add("Hosea");
        intList.Add("Hosea");
        intList.Add("Arthur");
        intList.Add("Dutch");
        intList.Add("Javier");
        intList.Add("Arthur");
        intList.Add("Marshton");
        intList.Add("Abigail");
```

So with those I want to search like Arthur on how many index duplicate he has and display the result.

I am trying to create this on console app.

Please I need the most basic and not Linq included.

Using only loops like foreach/for/while.

Thanks.

I got helped from other forums. Here is the code that fits my needs. Without Linq.

```
        List<string> intList = new List<string>();
        intList.Add("Hosea");
        intList.Add("Hosea");
        intList.Add("Arthur");
        intList.Add("Dutch");
        intList.Add("Javier");
        intList.Add("Arthur");
        intList.Add("Marshton");
        intList.Add("Abigail");            

        Console.WriteLine("Enter name to search for duplicates.");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        for (int i = 0; i < intList.Count; i++)
        {
            if (intList[i].Equals(input))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }

        if (intList.Contains(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Those are the index/indices of " + input + ".");
        }

        else
            Console.WriteLine("I guess you're out of luck. That bandit is not here.");

        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Linq to the rescue. There is an overload of `select`that also takes the index:

```cs
var result = intList.Select((value, index) => (value, index))
                    .GroupBy(valueAndIndex => valueAndIndex.value)
                    .Select(group => (group.Key, indices: group.Select(element => element.index)));

var formatted = result.Select(x => (x.Key, string.Join(", ", x.indices)));
```

This will return (in the intermediate window):

```
formatted.ToArray()
{(string, string)[6]}
    [0]: ("Hello", "0, 1")
    [1]: ("Arthur", "2, 5")
    [2]: ("Dutch", "3")
    [3]: ("Javier", "4")
    [4]: ("Marshton", "6")
    [5]: ("Abigail", "7")
```

Without Linq:

```cs
Dictionary<string, List<int>> results = new();

for(int i = 0; i < intList.Length; i++)
{
    string item = intList[i];
    if(!results.TryGetValue(item, out var indices))
        results[item] = indices = new List<int>();
    
    indices.Add(i);
}
```

You will now have an entry in the dictionary for each item containing all indices.

Comment: Sorry, is there a way not to use Linq? Not like I don't want it but I just need to know the most basic way and by not using Linq or Dictionaries.

Comment: I can show you a more basic way with dictionaries if you want. However, without dictionaries you won't be using a fitting data structure and I am not inclined to show bad examples.

Comment: Yes please. Dictionaries is fine.

Comment: Added the solution without Linq but using Dictionaries