# Can't display correct indices of user selected list item

Tags: c#, list, foreach

I have a standard string list : `List<string>` My goal is to have a program traverse through the list, collect the indices of all strings and then display a user chosen string's respective index, or idices if it's repeated. I also have an if statement to catch if a user input does not match an entry from the list. I am using .ToLower() to try and format the user input as well.

This is what I have so far and it's behaving very unexpectedly:

```
List<string> moneyList = new List<string>()
{
    "$100 bill",
    "penny",
    "$10 bill",
    "dime",
    "$100 bill",
    "silver dollar",
    "$10 bill",
    "quarter",
    "$5 bill",
    "quarter",
    "silver dollar",
    "nickel",
    "$50 bill",
    "penny",
    "$20 bill",
    "$50 bill",
    "nickel",
    "$1 bill",
    "$5 bill",
    "$20 bill",
    "dime",
    "$1 bill"
};

    Console.Write(
        "Please choose from the following:\nPenny\nNickel\nDime\nQuarter\nSilver Dollar\n$1 bill\n" +
        "$5 bill\n$10 bill\n$20 bill\n$50 bill\n$100 bill\n\nType your choice here\n>>>: ");


    string userMoney = Console.ReadLine();
    string userMoneyLower = userMoney.ToLower();

    string[] moneyArray = moneyList.ToArray();

    bool isNotInList = false;

    foreach (string money in moneyList)
    {
        if (userMoneyLower == money)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(moneyList.IndexOf(money));
        }
        else
        {
            isNotInList = true;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\n");

    // Assignment 10 - Message is not in list
    if (isNotInList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Sorry, your choice isn't in the List. Maybe try again later?");
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nEnter to Continue . . .");
    Console.ReadLine();
```

This is what my program returns:

[image: Output of program in console]

Please let me know why it's repeating the same index (3) twice instead of let's say 3 and 20 as dime from the list should return.

Comment: `IndexOf()` always returns the first instance. That's why it's returning 3 both times.

Comment: And are you writing this program this way because it's part of a course/class and you're supposed to? Because this is very convoluted way of doing things.

Comment: @Sach Yes, it is written with `for, foreach, if, else,` etc. and not using `LINQ` because the assignment requests it. We haven't gone over LINQ as of yet, but I'm slightly familiar and do agree that the second option from your answer down below is much cleaner and less convoluted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your immediate question, that why it prints `3` both times, is that the function `IndexOf()` [returns the index of the first item in the list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.indexof?view=netframework-4.7.2) that matches your condition. In other words, think of it as `FirstIndexOf()`. Please read the linked documentation for more details.

After that, let me comment on your code a little bit. You can do it the way you are trying, but it's a bit convoluted and redundant. There are easier ways.

### Option 1

We can have a secondary `List<int>` to store all the indices we find (if any). Then iterate the list, and if we find a matching item, store it in the index list. I'm gonna get rid of all the clutter, and assume that the `userMoneyLower` variable has the user input converted to lower case.

```
string userMoneyLower = "dime";

var indices = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < moneyList.Count; i++)
{
    if (moneyList[i] == userMoneyLower)
    {
        // If we find a matching item, we store the index
        indices.Add(i);
    }
}

if (indices.Count == 0)
{
    // not in list
}
else
{
    // found 1 or more times
}
```

Next, if you're allowed to and/or want to, you can use `LINQ` and get all this done in one line of code.

### Option 2

```
var indices2 = moneyList
            .Select((val, index) => val == userMoneyLower ? index : -1)
            .Where(x => x != -1)
            .ToList();
```

**Explanation:**

- The `Select()` method tells it to go through the list, and *select* the index of each item.
- But there's a caveat; it replaces the index with -1 if the item at that index doesn't match `userMoneyLower`.
- So at the end of the `Select()` you will have a list of integers with values containing either `-1`, or a `value >= 0`.
- The next `Where()` is telling it to do a sort of filtering and pick only the values that are not `-1`.
- The last `ToList()` simply converts it to a list.

Answer (score 1):

I see your issue, I will try to explain:

***Why it's printing 3 twice:***

When the program is iterating through, it first sees that you typed in `Dime`. So it will get to the if statement and go "oh the input is equal to this current iteration value" and spit out 3 as it's the 4th item in the list (C# collections are 0 Index based meaning item 1 in the collection is index 0). This is expected behaviour as far as I can tell. Your problem is that when it comes to see that your input is equal to the 2nd occurrence of "Dime" it'll get the index again, however C# doesn't know what one you want so returns the first occurrence of it which is index 3 and as Dime appears twice you get 3 printed twice.

***As for your other issue:***

The program is saying it's failed because when it iterates through, the first item isn't equal to your input so it marks `isNotInList` as true and is never set to false again if the item is found. What you should probably do is break out of the loop when you find a matching item and set `isNotInList` to false when you do so.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Yes, it now makes much more sense. Thank you. Just out of curiosity, is there a way to tell the computer that I'd want all indices? A `IndexOfAll()` as it were?

Comment: There isn't a method like that. Your best bet is probably looking at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2718822/what-is-the-most-elegant-way-to-find-index-of-duplicate-items-in-c-sharp-list) and modifying it for your use

Comment: Alternatively, you could switch to a for loop and save the indexes where the input appears to a different collection, or a straight up string.

Answer (score 1):

IndexOf() will return the index of the first occurrence of the item in the list. https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOf()` will search for the specified object and returns the index of its first occurrence in a one-dimensional array or in a range of elements in the array.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.indexof?view=netcore-3.1

Maybe you should be looking to use `Contains()`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does clarify the use of `IndexOf()` for me. As far as `Contains()` goes, while that is a decent alternative, the output is a `Boolean` as apposed to an index. While it can be made to work, it makes you think if there's a direct alternative to `IndexOf()` that works more like an `IndexOfAll()`?

Comment: Hey @ScottK. Yeah your right. if you need the specific index where it happened.
Then maybe you could Where() to filter the one where it doesn't contain.
Or even better to get the indexes use a `Select((t, index) => ...)`.
Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Hi, because it was an assignment they wanted us to use looping statements instead of LINQ. But yes, using `Where()` and `Select()` are much better alternatives. I ended up using the method posted by @Sach. With a little bit of alteration to make it work for my assignment. I’ll post it here just in case you were to ever come across this again. Thanks!